# How to represent CDI interceptors in class diagram?

Tags: java, class-diagram, java-ee, aspect-oriented

I have the following classes:

```
public class MyCaller{
    @Inject private MyService service;

    private void callerMethod(int arg1, String arg2){
        service.serviceMethod(arg1, arg2);
    }    
}


@Transactional
public class MyService{
    @MyAutorizationInterceptor(ADMINS_ONLY)
    public void serviceMethod(@MyValidator int arg1, @NotBlank String arg2){
        //logic
    }
}
```

There are some interceptors that are either built-in with Java EE capabilities (`@Transactional`) or custom made (`@MyAuthorizationInterceptor`).

Also, when a method is called the parameters gets validated against the annotation they're annotated with (`@MyValidator` is a custom validator, `NotBlank` is a built-in validator). If a constraint gets violated an exception occurs. The validators are triggered by a Bean Validator (**JSR 380**) implementation (in my case *Apache BVal*).

The question is: how should i depict these interceptors/validators in my class diagram? Should they be connected to each class they're applied on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends on the attribute and the role it plays in the system. I will first focus on `@NotBlank` and `@MyValidator`.

Since NotBlank comes with the framework, I wouldn't bother including that in the diagram. Remember that class diagrams are a communication and design tool. Something this basic is not worth including. Developers should get to know the framework. This is not your responsibility as the author of a class diagram. Validators are used to check for business rule violations. The built-in validators feel like you are encoding business rules in a class diagram.

Custom validators are different. They represent code that your team needs to write. Defining a dependency relationship between the validator and the class is validates is a useful design artifact for the team. In this case I would use a directed dependency:

```
+---------------------+                      +---------------------+
| MyValidatorProperty | --- (validates) ---> | SomeClass           |
```

This communicates the structure of the application, and gives teammates names for things without requiring diagram authors to document a 3rd party framework.

Lastly, I will address the `@Transactional` property. In addition to this property part of the framework, it also represents a transactional boundary in the application. Information like this is not well-suited for a class diagram. A UML Sequence diagram is probably a better tool, because when to commit changes is a matter of application flow.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I still have some doubts: considering that some validators **may** be applied to all classes (just like  the ``@NotBlank`` validator. It can be applied just anywhere), should I just go with grouping all the interceptors/validators in their own package (say, ``com.app.validators``, for example) and then just depict the relationship ``com.app.validators ---> com.app.service`` in a package diagram? The alternative would be depicting the relationship each class, but that would lead in a untangled and unmantainable web of connections.

Comment: @cidra: it all comes back to depicting the useful relationships between classes. If it is not useful as a design tool, don't include it.